# ASP.NET MVC - Azure redis session does not keep the values if they are saved in long processing method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, session, redis

In my post action, I simple put the simple code as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test()
{            
   Session["mykey"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:ss");
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000);
   return View();
}
```

In debugging, when I clicked on the submit button, the Session contained correct value. But when I submitted again, the Session did not contain "**mykey**"(Session["mykey"] is null).
This did not happen if I removed **Thread.Sleep** method or set the short time (e.g. System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(**10000**))

The config setting in my application is as follows:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         host="myhost.cache.windows.net" port="6380" 
         accessKey="myaccesskey" 
         ssl="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Could you please give me your ideas? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you are using the [Azure Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider) as your session state provider. Have you tried to access `Session["mykey"]` after Thread.Sleep? Moreover, you could follow [What happened to my data in Redis?](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/b6354d92a2d51c141490f10142884ea4#file-whathappenedtomydatainredis-md) to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: @BruceChen, I could access Session["mykey"] value after Thread.Sleep but this value did not exist in later requests. Thank you for the link. I will take a look at it.